# How to get values from one table based on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a table with the name of other tables in one column.

So now I need check if these tables have certain value in the first row.

After that if the table has that value I can show that table as a row in the first table; for example on MAIN TABLE, I put all the names of the other tables.

I expect if the tables has the value 1 in the first row it will be returned.

The number of tables change always, and the first value in the other tables change as well

The example is something like this

```
MAIN TABLE
------------
| table_name|  
| a         |  
| b         |  
| c         |  
| d         |  

a        
--------
| value|
--------
| 0    |

b       
--------
| value|
--------
| 1    |

c    
--------
| value|
--------
| 1   |

d      
--------
| value|
--------
| 0    |

RESULT EXPECTED
------------
| table_name|  
| b         |  
| c         |
```

Comment: What do you mean with "register"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, register for a row in the table, that's what I mean

Comment: Do you mean a column?

Comment: Nop, i mean a row in the main table

Comment: Well, "rows" don't contain values. The contain _columns_ which in turn contain the values.

Comment: Maybe the meaning change a lot in english, Un registro, fila o tupla representa un objeto único de datos implícitamente estructurados en una tabla, for that I apologized for my bad english, that's the reason why I wrote register and row. I use those words to refer it.

Comment: And maybe the best solution was post on stackoverflow on spanish but, this community has more people.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the main table is named "names", other tables have names 'a', 'b', ... (as in your question), and value columns in a, b, c, ... are named 'myvalue', you will get the result with this function:

```
create or replace function have_ones(tcTableName text)
returns boolean as
$body$
declare
   lnResult int;
begin
   lnResult := 0;
   execute ('select count(*) from ' || tcTableName || ' where myvalue = 1;') into lnResult;
   return ( lnResult > 0 );
end;
$body$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

Function uses dynamically created query, that depends on table name.

With this function defined, you will get result in following query:

```
select table_name from names where have_ones(names.table_name);
```